# Encoding large file(500MB+) to base64 in python

Tags: python, encoding, base64

I am trying to base64 encode a large exe file which is around 500 MB and while doing it i am getting this error:

```
F:\python\waft>python count.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "count.py", line 10, in <module>
    encodedZip = base64.b64encode(f.read())
  File "C:\Users\rohan-pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\base64.py", line 58, in b64encode
    encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s, newline=False)
MemoryError
```

This is the code i wrote to generate base64 from exe. I did some research and got to know that there are some memory limitation but is there any other way that i can encode larger files..?

```
with open("test.exe", "rb") as f:
    encodedZip = base64.b64encode(f.read())
```

Comment: try ```data = open("test.exe", "rb").read()``` and then ```encoded = base64.b64encode(data)```

Comment: @IbtihajTahir nope. getting same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research i got the answer the following code works :

```
fr = open("test.exe", 'rb')

i = 1
while True:
    piece = fr.read(75232000)
    if not piece:
        break
    fw = open(str(i), 'wb')
    fw.write(base64.b64encode(piece))
    fw.close()
    i += 1
fr.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from base64io import Base64IO

with open("test.exe", "rb") as f:
    encodedZip = Base64IO(f)
```

You can use a streaming interface for Base64 encoding by using the [base64io](https://pypi.org/project/base64io/) library. This would divide it into chunks and then before the base64 operation. This would be a better way to manage memory for encoding large files.

```
pip install base64io
```

Comment: DIdnt work. I got this error : TypeError: object of type 'Base64IO' has no len()

Answer (score 1):

This is the best solution as I know:

```
import base64
base64.encode(open(input_file, "rb"), open(output_file, "wb"))
```

This will read the file block by block and not all in one time, so it will not consume all your RAM...

You can write it as follow if you need some other action on the files:

```
import base64
with open(input_file, "rb") as fin:
    with open(output_file, "wb") as fout:
        fout.write(some_header)
        base64.encode(fin, fout)
        fout.write(some_footer)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading, encoding and writing in chunks, preferably by using a library like [base64io](https://pypi.org/project/base64io/).